# How do I handle an observable with the async pipe in a textbox value for Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have an observable that returns a custom object - I want to use the `async` pipe to get a property out of the object in the observable.  When I use the following syntax, the `<input />` value is just `[object Object]?.color`

```
<input type="text" value="{{myObservable$ | async}}?.color"></input>
```

Comment: Try use `[value]="(myObservable$ | async)?.color"` instead

Comment: @user184994, I tried that and got this error: `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{myObservable$ | async}}?.color]`

Comment: Yeah, just updated that comment, try that

Comment: @user184994, got it.  That did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by

Property binding

```
<input type="text" [value]="(myObservable$ | async)?.color"></input>
```

Template expression

```
<input type="text" value="{{*myObservable$ | async).?.color}}"></input>
```

> in your question `?.color` was not part of the template expression